# What is the character for the SHIFT + 1 key combination on a US keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I recently setup a new password for a Gmail account unfortunately I no longer know the password and the account recovery option is unable to verify my account.

I have a good idea of the password I originally created however it doesn't seem to work - I am thinking maybe this was caused by a keyboard layout problem - e.g every now and then when I press the [SHIFT] key and 2 it gives me the @ sign rather than the " character (double quote). I am thinking maybe a similar thing happened but with the exclamation key.

Sometimes the keyboard layout switches between US and UK, I was thinking maybe the same issue has happened again - what I want to know is the exclamation mark ([SHIFT] + 1) what would this key combination be on a US keyboard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The US keyboard places ! at shift-1. You can find diagrams of many common keyboard layouts at http://kbd-intl.narod.ru/english/layouts.